# How do I speed up the JVM?

Tags: java, linux

I'm writing some java software that is being run on both Linux and Windows XP Embedded on a Vortex86 Chip. The software usually loads in 2-3 seconds in Windows XP but when I try and load it in Linux it takes around 10-12 seconds. I don't think its a code optimization issue because it takes 1 second to run a Hello World program.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Pre-loading java is an option because the machine will only be running these programs but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Way too many possible factors at play to say, at least without more information.

Comment: is this an executable jar? are you using a container like spring? do you do any bootstrap code that might affect this? we really need more info. i.e: hardware info of both xp and linux machines, are they the same? are they running the same jvm? which jvm are you using? etc

Comment: are you using the same jvm on both platforms? the server runtime starts slower, but runs faster than the normal jre.

Answer (score 2):

As Matt pointed out, there are many factors at play.  With your incomplete description, it's impossible to make targeted recommendations.  Having said that, here are a few things to try :

- Profile your memory utilization with -verbose:gc and increase the memory allotted to your program (java -Xms512m -Xmx512m)
- Check that the version of Java on both machines is roughly equivalent
- Check that the hardware on both machines is roughly equivalent
- Check whether both machines are quiet when you're measuring performance
- Make sure both are running in either 32-bit or 64-bit, and you're not reporting results from a mixed profile.
- Check for startup scripts that your program may be using for one platform, but may be missing for the other (e.g a run.properties)

Comment: It is the same machine, and Java is the same on both Operating Systems. I'm running in 32-bit. It is also an executable Jar file that I'm loading

Comment: OK - attach a profiler and see if the program is behaving differently.  Is your program doing any I/O?

Comment: Also, how can it be the same machine?  Is one of them a virtual image?  That will slow you down certainly!

Comment: Amir, its a panel PC with an CF Hard Drive so I just swap out the drives. My program is doing some IO but nothing at the loading.

Comment: Try the profiler approach.  If the profiles look similiar, my guess is something else is starving the process for CPU on your linux rig.

Answer (score 2):

If you have run Java before, the shared files and rt.jar will be in memory. i.e. pre-loaded for you. I can only imagine your Linux machine is very low on memory and it has to load everything from disk each time.

On my Linux box

```
$ time java -cp . HelloWorld
Hello World.

real     0m0.043s
user     0m0.030s
sys      0m0.010s
```

The total time to start and run is 0.043 seconds.  Can you do a similar test with your hello world?

Comment: real  0m1.002; user  0m0.730s; sys  0m0.83s;

Comment: What is the hardware you are using? How much free memory do you have?

Comment: Using a 1GHz processor and i have about 300mb of ram